# PHP curl and getting HTTPS site's html source code

Tags: php, curl, https

I wrote this code for getting https pages content but i couldnt succesfull.

```
 <?php

    function bot($url)
    {
        $header ="Host: tr-tr.facebook.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0\r\n
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br";
        $options = array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_PORT => 443,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
                CURLOPT_CAINFO => "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\curl-ca-bundle.crt",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => explode("\r\n",$header)

            );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
    }
        echo bot("https://tr-tr.facebook.com");
    ?>
```

When i run that codes it is returning that. "��0#a�jȌ#�#.3�j�##u�.����/#cw@,�q=ߓ���K"<�˞#%#����t[�d�:|��s@#$!� ��(��M��ߛ#w'#u" Where is my mistake? Why is returning these characters?

I dont want to use `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false`. I want to https handshake with curl..

Comment: It looks like the response is [Brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli) encoded. Either try to negotiate a different encoding or decode it yourself. [`Content-Encoding: br`](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/bZd7o)

Comment: When I remove the accept encoding header I get the plain text https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/eZd7o or you can just negotiate gzip if you support that, because the servers is happy to give you gzip instead.

Comment: Yes thats work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` or handle it properly.

From the manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Do you really want this?!

```
> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER

> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the
> return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER = false but the output is same. Have you ever tried connecting https with curl, not with curlopt_ssl_verifypeer=false? I am wondering why am I getting this output?

Comment: Well then set `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` and see what happens. I could also be something with compression. so just remove the whole **Accept...** header and try it with verbose.